# Undefined value when passing text to twitter web intent

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter

I have JQuery code that passes a quote (which is randomly generated when a button is clicked) to twitter. However, when you open the new window to tweet the quote it displays a value of undefined as oppose to the actual quote.

Here is the Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
  var result;
function getQuotes(){ 

  var quotes = [ "Thousands of candles can be lighted from a single candle, and the life of the candle will not be shortened. Happiness never decreases by being shared.-\n Buddha",
"Happiness is the art of never holding in your mind the memory of any unpleasant thing that has passed.\n-Unknown",
"To be happy, we must not be too concerned with others.\n-Albert Camus",
"If you want happiness for an hour — take a nap.If you want happiness for a day — go fishing.If you want happiness for a year — inherit a fortune.If you want happiness for a lifetime — help someone else."]

var result = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)]; 

document.getElementById("stuff").innerHTML = result; 

}
  $("#tweet").on('click',function(){
  window.open("http://www.twitter.com/intent/tweet?text="+result);

});
  $(document).on('click', '#quotes', function() {
    getQuotes();
});

  });
```

Here is a link to the codepen: http://codepen.io/sibraza/pen/KMPzxx?editors=1010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 different `result` variables due to using `var` twice. The only one that gets a value set is the one that is local inside `getQuotes()`

The other declared outside `getQuotes()` is always undefined.

Try changing

```
var result = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)];
```

To

```
result = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)];
```